# The specified container does not exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, azure, blob, azure-storage

Am stuck with this error `The specified container does not exist.`

let me explain,

```
CloudBlobClient blobStorage = GetBlobStorage("upload");
CloudBlockBlob blob = BlobPropertySetting(blobStorage, Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToLower() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName));
blob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream);

public static CloudBlobClient GetBlobStorage(string cloudBlobContainserName)
{
    CloudBlobClient blobStorage;

    try
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("StorageConnectionString");
        blobStorage = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobStorage.GetContainerReference(cloudBlobContainserName); 

        container.CreateIfNotExist();

        var permissions = container.GetPermissions();
        permissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;

        container.SetPermissions(permissions);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.LogError(Log4NetLogger.Category.Exception, "Error in : BlobHandler.GetBlobStorage :>> Exception message: " + ex.Message);
        throw;
    }

    return blobStorage;
}

public static CloudBlockBlob BlobPropertySetting(CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClientReferenceName, string blobContentName)
{
    return cloudBlobClientReferenceName.GetBlockBlobReference(blobContentName);
}
```

and my `StorageConnectionString` is

```xml
<Setting name="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=duw;AccountKey=bla bla" />
```

container 'upload' and the storage account 'duw' exist.

executing `blob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream);` statement causes the error.

stack trace :

> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TaskImplHelper.ExecuteImpl(Func`1 impl)
> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlob.UploadFromStream(Stream source, BlobRequestOptions options)
> at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlob.UploadFromStream(Stream source)
> at DAL.Handlers.BlobHandler.CreateAd(HttpPostedFileBase file, Advertisement model) in D:\DU Server\trunk\Du Server\DAL\Handlers\BlobHandler.cs:line 151

Inner exception:

`{"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."}`

can any body help me to sort this out.

Comment: first thing to do is to check if container is being created properly using any of azure storage viewers.like cloudstorageexplorer.
secondly, see if you are getting reference of blob properly in BlobPropertySetting method?

Comment: blobStorage.GetContainerReference("upload") gives the following


{Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobContainer}
    Attributes: {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.BlobContainerAttributes}
    Metadata: {System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection}
    Name: "upload"
    Properties: {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.BlobContainerProperties}
    ServiceClient: {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobClient}
    Uri: {https://duw.blob.core.windows.net/upload}

Comment: I'm not sure i understand those first 3 lines.. are they class level vars or are you running those from another method not shown here?

Comment: @paqogomez: class level vars.. all methods i used are shown here..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Short version**

Try the following code for `BlobPropertySetting` function:

```
 public static CloudBlockBlob BlobPropertySetting(CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClientReferenceName, string blobContentName)
    {
        CloudBlockBlob blob = cloudBlobClientReferenceName.GetBlockBlobReference("upload/" + blobContentName);
        return blob;
    }
```

**Now for the longer version :)**

The reason you're getting this error is because of the way you are constructing the `CloudBlockBlob` object in `BlobPropertySetting` method. When you use your code, it creates a blob object with the following URI: `https://duv.blob.core.windows.net/blobContentName`. If you notice, there's no container name there. Since there's no container name, storage client library assumes that you're trying to create a blob in `$root` blob container which is a special blob container. You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh488356.aspx. Since your storage account does not have this container, you get `404 - Resource Not Found` error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending  your valuable time..
but am confused with the flow of code
CloudBlobContainer container = blobStorage.GetContainerReference(cloudBlobContainserName); 
            container.CreateIfNotExist();
these two lines are executed na..?

Comment: Yes, they are executed. You should see a blob container by the name "upload" in your storage account. Essentially you lost the reference to your container when you left that method. Yet another alternative would be to return an object of type `CloudBlobContainer` from this method instead of `CloudBlobClient`. Then in your `BlobPropertySetting` when you pass this blob container object, you don't have to prepend the name of the container in `GetBlockBlobReference`. HTH.

Answer (score 4):

I am very late, but still thought if my answer would be useful for anyone.

I resolved this error by putting the correct "container name". It was different by default.
I have cloned this GIT project : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-upload-from-webapp-node

```
const
      express = require('express')
    , router = express.Router()
    , azureStorage = require('azure-storage')
    , blobService = azureStorage.createBlobService()
    , containerName = 'container' // added container name here, as my container name
    , config = require('../config')
;
```

Comment: I was making the same mistake, even I forgot to change the container name. Now my service is starting up, but when trying to upload a file it is throwing 500 error in the upload.js file. TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined. Not sure what mistake I am making here.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are also setting the blob name correctly. An upload attempt to a valid container with a missing blob name will also return "404 Not Found".