# The specified blob does not exist

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

If my container name is longer(eg: offlineblob1  below) I am getting an error:

> "The specified blob does not exist"

If my container name is shorter(eg., offlineblob2 below), it works with out any errors.

But I need to create blobcontainers with longer names. Any thoughts on this error

My code is as follows :

```
string offlineblob1 =https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/offline800xyz09252013203652
string offlineblob2 =https://xyz.blob.core.windows.net/offline
var destBlob = blobClient.GetBlobReference(offlineblob1);
byte[] fileBytes = destBlob.DownloadByteArray(); //if I use offlineblob2 it works fine
```

Comment: I can only guess you need to check if offlineblob1 value is valid.

Comment: Yes,both the shorter and longer container's are valid and has files in it.

Comment: Please provide a better example: In your code snippet you try to download a container which is not itself a blob. The scheme should be http://<storage account>.blob.core.windows.net/<container>/<blob> ...

Comment: Please check if you are not running into the issue as in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18864002/the-specified-container-does-not-exist/18864697#18864697

Answer (score 0):

Your container names and blob names are not longer than allowed. Container names can be up to 63 characters (and must be at least 3 characters). Blob names can be up to 1024 characters.

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135715.aspx

I suspect that either the blob you are trying to download does not exist or there is a bug in your code that is creating the wrong URL for the blob. Your example code has URLs to containers, not blobs.